# No Subwoofer Sound with TerraTec 5.1 MkII in 2.1 or 4.1 Config (but works in 5.1 config)

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I have a TerraTec external USB Sound'card' which reports to lsusb as:

0ccd:0028 TerraTec Electronic GmbH Aureon 5.1 MkII

on Ubuntu 20 with Kernel 5.13.0-27-generic

In the Configuration 'Analog Surround 2.1 Output' there is no Subwoofer output when I click 'Test' and select the subwoofer. The same applies for the Configuraton 'Analog Surround 4.1 Output'.

But when I select 'Analog Surround 5.1 Output' the subwoofer test works. As I do only have 2.1 Speakers I would prefer the 2.1 Configuraton.

- funnily enough in 'pavumeter' I can see the Subwoofer test sound in all three configurations. (but the actual sound is only audible in 5.1)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If possible show the mixer configuration.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Screenshot, or copy&paste if you use the text interface.